# Error Provider not showing message and isn't blinking

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on windows application using C#

I have taken an errorprovider and validating NULL textBox as follows:

```
if (textBox1.Text == string.Empty)
{
    errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Please enter Value");
}
```

But when I run the program it is only showing icon but no message. It's not even blinking

What should I do?

Comment: null and an empty string are not the same thing.

Comment: You are probably validating it before the window is shown, thus not getting it to blink.  The message is easy to miss, it is a tooltip.  You also need an *else* clause that resets the error.

Answer (score 0):

The think the `textBox1.Text` is null. Use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text))
{
   errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1, "Please enter Value");
}
```